# How to check if value is inserted successfully or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure where I insert values into my table.

```
declare @fName varchar(50),@lName varchar(50),@check tinyint
INSERT INTO myTbl(fName,lName) values(@fName,@lName)
```

**EDITED:**

Now I want check if it inserted successfully set @check = 0 else @check = 1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` server variable immediately after the insert query to check number of affected rows by the insert operation.

```
declare @fName varchar(50) = 'Abcd',
        @lName varchar(50) = 'Efgh'
INSERT INTO myTbl(fName,lName) values(@fName,@lName)

PRINT @@ROWCOUNT --> 0- means no rows affected/nothing inserted 
                 --> 1- means your row has been inserted successfully
```

For your requirement, you could use a `Case` statement(as per comment):

```
--If you need @check as a bit type please change Int to bit
DECLARE @check Int = CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: thank you for answering , i correct my question if it inserted succesfully i need set @check = 0

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

It returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use `ROWCOUNT_BIG`.

> @@ROWCOUNT is both scope and connection safe.
>
> In fact, it reads only the last statement row count for that
>   connection and scope.
>
> It’s safe to use @@ROWCOUNT in SQL Server even when there is a trigger
>   on the base table. The trigger will not skew your results; you’ll get
>   what you expect. @@ROWCOUNT works correctly even when NOCOUNT is set.

so you query should be:

```
declare @fName varchar(50), @lName varchar(50), @check tinyint = 0
...
INSERT INTO myTbl(fName,lName) values(@fName,@lName)
if  @@ROWCOUNT>0   
  set @check = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@@rowcount` after insert table, like this:

```
DECLARE @check int

INSERT INTO Employees (Name,Email,Phone,[Address])
VALUES('Test','test@mail.com','','')

if(@@ROWCOUNT>0)
SET @check=1

SELECT @check;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-Sever you can use OUTPUT clause to check if values are inserted successfully.
By following query

```
 
declare @fName varchar(50),@lName varchar(50)

INSERT INTO myTbl(fName,lName) OUTPUT inserted.* values(@fName,@lName)  ;
```

IF the values are inserted it will show output of inserted values. You can also store these values into new table.

Comment: For detailed information on OUTPUT clause go to [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I can say you can simply check the previous numbers of rows before inserting the new.
for example previous you have 50 rows. just store the numbers of rows in a variable and check after the insert query if numbers of row increased or no.
yes little extra chunk of code but easy to understand