# Explicitly checking if an SQL INSERT operation succeeded unnecessary?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Python to talk to a Postgres DBMS using psycopg2.

Is it safe to assume that if an INSERT returns without raising an exception, then that INSERT actually did store something new in the database?

Right now, I've been checking the 'rowcount' attribute of the database cursor, and if it's 0 then that means the INSERT failed.  However, I'm starting to think that this isn't necessary.

Comment: Well: try it.add some invalid data to your inserts, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that if an INSERT returns without raising an
>   exception, then that INSERT actually did store something new in the
>   database?

No.

The affected record count will be zero if:

- You ran an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, and the query returned no rows
- You ran an `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, and it encountered a conflict
- You have a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on your table, and the [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) returned `NULL`
- You have a [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) defined which results in no records being affected (e.g. `... DO INSTEAD NOTHING`)

(... and possibly more, though nothing comes to mind.)

The common thread is that it will only affect zero records if *you told it to*, one way or another. Whether you want to treat any of these as a "failure" is highly dependent on your application logic.

Anything which is unequivocally a "failure" (constraint violation, serialisation failure, out of disk space...) should throw an error, so checking the record count is generally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

By default `postgres` will return `None` for a successful insert:

> `cursor.execute` - The method returns `None`. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

If you want to know something about the insert, an easy/efficient option is to use `RETURNING` (which takes the same options as a `SELECT`):

```
INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id
```

Answer (score -2):

found similar question here, [How to check if value is inserted successfully or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375579/how-to-check-if-value-is-inserted-successfully-or-not)

they seem to use the row count method to check if the data was inserted correctly.

Comment: The answer you've posted is for SQL Server, not PostgreSQL. He said that he is using rowcount. There is better way (using fetchone[0] on cursor after INSERT)

Comment: Whether or not this is the most efficient way to do it is moot, this isn't actually what the author was asking. He asked whether it was explicitly necessary not how to do it.